# what's the coefficient inverse polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

The polynomial $(1+x)^n$ has a form in coefficient $\sum_{i=0}^{n} w_ix^i$,  and i'm interested in this polynomail $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{w_i}x^i$, and is there any inverse presentation in the form of $\prod_{i=0}^{n} (1+k_ix)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in the case $n = 2$, this is hopeless.

$$  (1+x)^2 = 1+2x+x^2  \text{.}  $$

The polynomial
$$  P(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{2} x + x^2  $$
is not of the desired form.  In detail,
$$  P(x) = \left( x + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{\mathrm{i}}{4} \sqrt{15} \right)\left( x + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{\mathrm{i}}{4} \sqrt{15} \right)  $$
and if we force
$$  1+k_1 x = x + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{\mathrm{i}}{4} \sqrt{15}  \text{,}  $$
then
$$  k_1 = \frac{-3 + \mathrm{i}\sqrt{15} + 4x}{4x}  \text{,}  $$
which is not independent of $x$ (for instance, its values at $x=1$ and $x=2$ are different).